# calling a custom @helper method in ms web pages from a client side event

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I have a myPage.cshtml page. i have written a @helper method( myMethod() ) in myHelper.cshtml. I can call the helper method inline in the page ( @myHelper.myMethod(); ) and it works just fine.

How do i call this same method from a user initiated event like ( menu.item.click, button.click, link click ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your method executes in server-side code, you'll have to create a way to call the code on your server from the client. For example, you could have an action method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyHelperCaller()
{
    // Returns the contents of the 'myHelperCaller' view:
    return this.View();
}
```

...where the `myHelperCaller` View contains a call to your `myMethod()` helper method.

Then to call that from the client you'd use something like:

```
<div id="myHelperTarget"></div>
<input id="myHelperTrigger" type="button" value="Call MyHelper" />
<script language="text/javascript">

$("#myHelperTrigger").click(function () {
    // Loads the myHelperCaller view into the myHelperTarget div:
    $("#myHelperTarget").load("/MyController/MyHelperCaller");
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your input Steve! I am trying to implement this using the "web pages" programming model, so i dont really have models, views and controllers per se,to work with, just pages, is there any way to do this in that model?

Comment: Ah, ok! Fair enough - I think the same answer applies - you can have a web page which does nothing but call your helper method, then have your JQuery function call that, like `.load("/myHelperCaller.cshtml")`.

Comment: so YES that WORKS, 1] myHelperTrigger button calls 2] my client side javascript which opens the 3] myHelperCaller.cshtml page in a new window (the page only contains the call to myHelper.myMethod() and this executes perfectly),the PRoBlem now is that i have to workaround hiding the new window and assuming myMethod has any paramaters i will have to pass those along the chain as well(also do-able) BUT  

I just feel like i am hitting a thumbtack with sledgehammer or missing obvious to get this done a little more succinctly...

Thanks again Steve for your idea, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Yay! Glad it's working out - calling the `.load()` function on a JQuery-wrapped division *should* load the result into that division rather than open it in a new window... if my answer has helped out, please could you accept it? :)

Comment: **[06.09][UPDATE]**

1] so i created a hidden div "myHelperTarget" on the same page that i am calling myHelper from 2] using the myhelper trigger, 3] I added the jquery .load function to put the 4] "myhelperCaller" page into the "myHelperTarget" div
( this resolves/avoids having to workaround the new window prblem ) 5] i then then added my parameters to the method call and viola, it _works like a lucky charm_ to have the client side user initiated event calling the @helper function on demand vs inline.

Comment: Thank you so much quys... I've been experiencing the exact same issue and haven't had any luck for weeks now, but thanks to this question (and answer), I think I can get it to work.